# Values are staying in empty cells while scrolling

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

i've got the problem in one excel file, that if i scroll thorugh my sheet, that some values still stay on the screen in cells where they don't belong to.
you can see it here:
[image]
The shown cells are actually empty. I can "refresh" the view by minimizing excel to the taskbar and maximize it again.

The "ghost" values are very annoing. they are also displayed, if in there are other values in the new cells.

have anyone an idea why these values ghosting over my whole sheet?

some specs about my file:
- i've got 12 datasheets
- every sheet is using some sum()-functions
 - some sum()-functions are using other sheets as source for the data
- col A-G are fixed while scrolling

Comment: Do you have any panes frozen? Go to `view - freeze panes - unfreeze panes` if you do

Comment: i've mentioned this in the last line of my code... but the values are ghost values and not a result of a freezed pane